Code.org gamelab collisions working spontaneously
I know it sounds stupid but it's true, at least for me. For my FCOS class my final task was to make a game. I made a simple endless type game where a monkey has to avoid basketballs and collect bananas. For some reason, all of the collisions work about 1/3 of the time. I really can't figure out why that is, neither can my teacher. Here's the code (collisions in the pleasegodwork functions and game function).
//Changes screen between tutorial and game and death
var screeb = 4;
//Starting text
var starttext = text('GUY GAME!!!');
//Misc variables mainly used in place of time functions SINCE CODE.ORG HAS NONE!
var wait1 = 0;
var bananatime = randomNumber(0,50);
var ballstime = randomNumber(0,50);
var bananaspeed = 7;
var basketballspeed = 3;
var basketbadguy = 'nothing';
var score = 0;
var lives = 3;
var emptyheart1 = 420;
var emptyheart2 = 'lol';

//Start button
var startbutton = createSprite(690,4200);
startbutton.setAnimation("start_button");
startbutton.scale = 1.5;

//Monkey/player
var guy = createSprite(690,420);
guy.setAnimation("guy");
guy.scale = 0.3;

//Banana/Target
var banana = createSprite(690,420);
banana.setAnimation("bannana");
banana.scale = 0.25;

//Basketball/Enemy
var basketball = createSprite(690,690);
basketball.setAnimation("basketball");
basketball.scale = 0.15;

//Platform with a stupid name
var ground = createSprite(690,690);
ground.setAnimation("ground");
ground.scale = 0.5;

var heart1 = createSprite(690,690);
heart1.setAnimation('heart1')
heart1.scale = 0.4;

var heart2 = createSprite(690,690);
heart2.setAnimation('heart1')
heart2.scale = 0.4;

var heart3 = createSprite(690,690);
heart3.setAnimation('heart1')
heart3.scale = 0.4;

function draw() {
  //Changes screens for easier testing and because I cant ur not my dad
  //Tutorial Screen
  if (screeb == 1){
    tutorialscreen();
  }
  //Game
  if (screeb == 2){
    reset();
    background('white')
    guy.x = 200;
    guy.y = 300;
    ground.x = 200;
    ground.y = 407;
    ground.scale = 1.5;
    basketball.x = 690;
    basketball.y = 690;
    heart1.x = 50;
    heart1.y = 50;
    heart2.x = 125;
    heart2.y = 50;
    heart3.x = 200;
    heart3.y = 50;
    screeb = 3;
  }
  //Actual game did you belive me loser
  if (screeb == 3){
    game()
  }
  //game over :()
  if (screeb == 4){
    gameover()
  }  
  // update sprites and check lives
  pleasegodwork();
  pleasegodwork2();
  pleasegodwork3();

}

//What did you think it was?
function tutorialscreen(){
  reset();
  textSize(40);
  fill('black');
  text('You are guy ->',0,150);
  guy.x = 340;
  guy.y = 150;
  startbutton.x = 200;
  startbutton.y = 50;
  startbutton.alpha = 0;
  wait1 = wait1 + 1;
  if (wait1 > 50){
    text('You like bananas ->', 0, 250);
    banana.x = 360;
    banana.y = 250;
  }
  if (wait1 > 100){
    textSize(30);
    text('Avoid the basketballs -> ',15,350);
    basketball.x = 360;
    basketball.y = 350;
  }
  if (wait1 > 150){
    startbutton.alpha = 1;
  }
  if (mousePressedOver(startbutton)){
    screeb = 2;
  }

}

//Moves stuff out of sight
function reset(){
  startbutton.x = 690;
  startbutton.y = 690;
  guy.x = 690;
  guy.y = 690;
  banana.x = -690;
  banana.y = -690;
  guy.x = -690;
  guy.y = -450;
  ground.x = 690;
  ground.y = 690;
  heart1.x = 690;
  heart2.x = 690;
  heart3.x = 690;
  emptyheart1.x = 690;
  emptyheart2.x = 690;
  basketball.x = 690;
}

//Game screen COME ON NOW!
function game(){
  //Timers
  bananatime += 1;
  ballstime += 1;
  backgroundselect = background("gray");
  backgroundselect.setAnimation = 'bg8';
  pleasegodwork();
  pleasegodwork2();
  pleasegodwork3();
  fill('white')
  text(score, 100,100);
  /////////////Movement/////////////////
  if (keyDown("right")){
    guy.velocityX = 7;
    guy.rotation += 5;
    
  } else if(keyDown('left')){
    guy.velocityX = -7;
    guy.rotation -= 5;
  } else {
    guy.velocityX = 0;
  }
  /////////Banana touch ground bad///////////////
  ///////////Teleports guy back around/////////////
  if (guy.x>440){
    guy.x = -30
  } else if (guy.x < -40){
    guy.x = 430
  }
  /////////////Banana falling yknow//////////////
  if (bananatime > 100){
    banana = createSprite(randomNumber(30,370));
    banana.setAnimation("bannana");
    banana.velocityY = bananaspeed;
    banana.scale = 0.2;
    bananatime = randomNumber(0,75);
  }
  //////////Basketball falling you don't know////
  if (ballstime > 100){
    basketball = createSprite(randomNumber(30,370));
    basketball.setAnimation("basketball");
    basketball.velocityY = basketballspeed;
    basketball.scale = 0.17;
    ballstime = randomNumber(0,75);
  }
}

///Checks collisions banana x guy
function pleasegodwork(){
////////Banana touch guy good!/////////////////
  if (banana.isTouching(ground)){
    banana.y = -20;
    console.log('help');
  }
  if (banana.isTouching(guy)){
    bananatime = randomNumber(0,75);
    score = score + 1;
    banana.y = -20;
    banana.x = randomNumber(30,360);
  }
  drawSprites();
  
}

//Checks collisions basketball x guy
function pleasegodwork2(){
  if (basketball.isTouching(ground)){
    basketball.y = -20;
  }
  if (basketball.isTouching(guy)){
    lives = lives - 1;
    basketball.y = -20;
    console.log('what')
  }
}

//Checks lives hunter x hunter
function pleasegodwork3(){
  if (lives == 2){
    emptyheart1 = createSprite(200,50);
    emptyheart1.setAnimation("empty1");
    emptyheart1.scale = 0.4;
    heart3.x = 690;
    heart3.y = 690;
  } 
  if (lives == 1){
    emptyheart2 = createSprite(125,50);
    emptyheart2.setAnimation('empty1');
    emptyheart2.scale = 0.4;
    heart2.x = 690;
    heart2.y = 690;
  }
  if (lives == 0){
    screeb = 4
  }
}

//if i have to keep explaining im gonna snap
function gameover(){
  reset();
  background('black');
  fill('white');
  textSize(35);
  text('You lost!',200,100);
  text('Your score was: ',200, 150);
  text(score, 200, 200 );
  startbutton.x = 200;
  startbutton. y = 300;
  drawSprites();
  if (mousePressedOver(startbutton)){
    screeb = 2;
  }
}


Share the definition of the isTouching function

Checks if the sprite is touching the target sprite or any sprite in the target group

I meant, share the implementation of isTouching. It's possible the bug is in that function

The implementation is I guess just to check if the two sprites are colliding with each other to make events happen

I meant share the actual function body for isTouching. Did you write this function?

@24bit as @Evert said please share the function isTouching. For example function isTouching() {//your code}

one problem i'm seeing with the code before running it is that there are a lot of missing semicolons, which, if this wasnt code.org, would be a huge critical error. another thing is that in the game function there is an undefined variable being used. these are the only errors that i can see without actually having the project, because without the original textures, i can't actually run the project. let me know if this helps at all by replying to this message.

"one problem i'm seeing with the code before running it is that there are a lot of missing semicolons, which, if this wasnt code.org, would be a huge critical error." Semicolons are optional in javaScript.
